# MyTouch 3g - WebView crashes when visiting Google.com (geolocation?)

Tags: android, webview, crash

There is no force close dialog; my app just exits after loading most of the page. There is also no stack trace in LogCat, but sometimes I see this error:

`E/geolocationService(580): Caught security exception registering for location updates from system. This should only happen in DumpRenderTree.`

But when I visit other sites that use geolocation, they do not crash.

I tried running in debug mode, and I found this error:

`E/ActivityManager(89): ANR in com.google.android.apps.docs`

`E/ActivityManager(89): Reason: Broadcast of Intent { act=android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE flg=0x30000000 cmp=com.google.android.apps.docs/.receivers.NetworkChangeReceiver (has extras) }`

followed by some CPU load statistics. (No useful results when googling this error).

I've tried adding the necessary permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_GPS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_ASSISTED_GPS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION" />
```

as well as enabling geolocation in the code:

```
        mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

        mWebView.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);
        mWebView.getSettings().setDatabaseEnabled(true);
        mWebView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);

        mWebView.getSettings().setGeolocationEnabled(true);
        mWebView.getSettings().setGeolocationDatabasePath(<path>);
```

I've also tried overriding WebChromeClient.onGeolocationPermissionsShowPrompt() to always return true (or false), but nothing helped.

Geolocation doesn't have to work; just getting it not to crash is good enough for me.

I'm using T-Mobile myTouch 3g, running Android 2.2.1.

EDIT: Also, this issue does not happen on Xoom or Galaxy SII Skyrocket.